# Как узнать, что OracleCommand уже находится в состоянии Prepared?

Tags: c#, oracle

Имею *WinForm* приложение и БД *Oracle*, к которой нужно корректно подключиться.

"Корректно" это вот так: если в момент выдачи очередного запроса кто-то выдернет сетевой шнур сервера из розетки, программа у клиента не виснет, а начинает тестировать связь с сервером (в цикле `ping`, затем `tnsping`, затем `select * from dual`) и после того как сервер снова оживёт, автоматически обратно коннектится и продолжает работу. Для этих целей написан код внизу, который выполняется в начале каждого обращения к БД из модулей программы.

```
 private static Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection oconn;
 private static Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand ocmd;
...
            do try {
                if (oconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) oconn.Open();
                if ((SQL.Length > 0) && (ocmd.CommandText != SQL)) ocmd.CommandText = SQL;   
                // вставить проверку: Prepared?, 
                // повторно Prepare() не выдавать, чтобы не валить сервер разборами запросов.
                ocmd.Prepare(); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                if (!uConnectTest.ConnectTest(null, e.Message)) { // модальный вызов модуля тестирования
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    return false; 
                };
            } while (oconn.State != ConnectionState.Open); // ??? вставить проверку успешности Prepare()
```

Дополнительно: хотелось бы держать часто выполняемый запрос в `ocmd.CommandText` открытым (в состоянии `Prepared`) в течении сессии, чтобы не валить сервер запросами, требующими разбора.
В цикле в блоке `try/catch` выполняются `oconn.Open()`, затем `ocmd.Prepare()`.
Выход из цикла должен состояться только при условии успешности обоих команд.
Я знаю, как проверить успешность только первой из них: `oconn.State != ConnectionState.Open`

**Вопрос**:
Как проверить, что `OracleCommand` уже находится в состоянии `Prepared` для принятия решения, что повторно выдавать запрос на сервер не нужно и можно уже присваивать параметры/выполнять запрос? Метод `Prepare()` у него есть, а вот свойства `Prepared` не нашёл. Плохо искал?

Буду признателен за рекомендации или тычок куда смотреть...

Comment: Я плохо знаю Oracle, но насколько мне известно, план запроса составляется и кэшируется на сервере в любом случае. Этот метод вообще можно не вызывать, он ничего не делает в реальности. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33667857/5045688

Comment: `...хотелось бы держать часто выполняемый запрос в ocmd.CommandText открытым (в состоянии Prepared) в течении сессии, чтобы не валить сервер запросами, требующими разбора.` в Оракл до сих пор еще не завезли хранимые процедуры?

Comment: >> в Оракл до сих пор еще не завезли хранимые процедуры? - Завезли. Но любое обращение к ХП - точно такой же SQL-запрос, требующий разбора, пусть в меньших объёмах. Кроме того, это немного усложнит систему в целом. Подумаю над этим, спасибо.

Comment: >> он ничего не делает в реальности. - Почитал. Прикольно, спасибо. Альтернативные инструменты (Devart ODAC) позволяют полностью контролировать взаимодействие клиента и СУБД, здесь же явно упрощение во вред производительности. Будем использовать то, что есть.

Comment: _находится в состоянии Prepared_, а что это за состояние, как вы его понимаете?

Comment: `...любое обращение к ХП - точно такой же SQL-запрос, требующий разбора...` может быть в Оракл оно и так, но в MS Sql Server точно нет.  Но вот это: `держать часто выполняемый запрос в ocmd.CommandText открытым` просто жалкий и убогий костылик по сравнению с работой через полноценную ХП. И в общем и остальные старания вроде этого `начинает тестировать связь с сервером (в цикле ping, затем tnsping, затем select * from dual` из этой же оперы. Почему не сделать проще: связь с сервером не установлена в течение опред. таймаута - сообщаем юзеру и ждем его действий: установить связь или выйти из прог

Comment: _вред производительности_ - нет никакого вреда. План запроса хранится в СУБД. При первом выполнении запроса этот запрос будет распарсен и составлен план. При всех повторных запросах используется этот план. / Всякие _prepared_ - это пережиток прошлого. Когда-то раньше имело смысл, сейчас - нет.

Comment: _Всякие prepared - это пережиток прошлого_, не совсем так. Подготовленные запросы, как были, так и остались. Или что вы понимаете под _prepared_?

Comment: Кроме упомянутого построения плана запроса оптимизатором, СУБД, получив на вход от клиента текст SQL, делает ещё очень много действий, например, проверяет права пользователя на каждый из объектов в запросе, проверяет статус каждой процедуры/функции, упомянутой в запросе и проч и проч. Когда-то я читал, что СУБД 90% времени тратит на разбор и только 10% - собственно на получение данных из блоков. Поэтому глупо заставлять сервер снова и снова выполнять эти процедуры (я уже молчу про не-параметризованные запросы, полагаю, всем понятно, что они фатальны для производительности сервера).

Comment: Prepared - это когда сервер полностью разобрал полученный текст SQL-запроса и завесил его как открытый запрос текущей сессии. Далее он получает от клиента только новые параметры и ищет строки в блоках данных, никаких затрат на служебные операции. Если вы пользуетесь TOAD, открытые запросы можно увидеть в "Database"-"Monitor"-"Session Browser".

Comment: >> почему не сделать проще: связь с сервером не установлена в течение опред. таймаута - сообщаем юзеру и ждем его действий: установить связь или выйти из прог – Уважаемый Bulson! сразу видно, что Вы не писали приложений для оперативного персонала, когда Вас за каждый такой сбой э-э-э... ругают. Вам быстро объяснили бы, что дядечкам некогда клацать вашими мышами а программа всё должна делать сама и быстро. Я ещё не описал в вопросе полностью процесс автоматической диагностики, который приходилось изобретать ;)

Comment: Сочувствую. [Тута](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3.2/odpnt/CommandPrepare.html#GUID-78190DD6-CFEE-403C-B51F-2C5388C3F558) пишут, что метод `Prepare` не поддерживается 

Comment: @NordRus Вы не совсем поняли, что такое Prepared. На сервере БД в контексте выполнения SQL запроса нет понятия Prepared. То, что вы называете:  _завесил его как открытый запрос текущей сессии_, правильно называется: открытый курсор.  _Далее он получает от клиента только новые параметры_, это называется batch query processing, которая закончится, если вы явно закроете курсор. При обрыве соединения, все ваши открытые курсоры, станут недействительны. Все ранние посланные запросы кэшируется в Library Cache и будут заново использованы, если будут открыты новые курсоры.

Comment: @NordRus То есть, вам нужно просто попытаться переоткрыть соединение, если оно оборвалось, и обрабатывать ошибку в случае, если эта попытка не удалась, никаких ping, tnsping делать не нужно. Вот ещё ссылка на оф.доку, где упрощённо  показано - [как выполнение запроса работает](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/sql-processing.html). PS всегда добавляйте в комментариях @ с ником участника, чтобы он получил уведомление.

Comment: @0xdb  Да, ссылка по делу. Всё же не соглашусь насчёт ping, tnsping: службе поддержки нужно получать от пользователя внятные сообщения о происходящем, а такое тестирование очень помогает диспетчеру ИТ-службы понять: что сделать и в какой ИТ-отдел адресовать запрос (направлять мужика чтобы он искал обрыв кабеля или DBA, чтобы он поднимал экземпляр). С точки зрения именно подключения к БД, конечно, никаких ping, tnsping не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Комментариев много, а ответа нет. Попробую я его дать.

Нужно рассмотреть две стороны: серверную и клиентскую.

---

На сервере (СУБД) все запросы парсятся, составляется план и он кэшируется. Далее этот план используется и повторно время не тратится на парсинг sql и его составление. Причём не важно, откуда пришёл этот запрос: например, из приложения на Java или на Python - если он уже есть в кэше, то будет взят оттуда.

Когда-то раньше, в прошлые десятилетия, это было не так. Планы хранимых процедур хранились, а обычных запросов - нет. Вот тогда имели смысл prepared - подготовленные запросы. Можно было явно указать СУБД сохранять план в кэше. С тех пор памяти стало немеряно, движки СУБД изменились, нужда в явном указании исчезла.

---

Теперь клиентская сторона.

Наличие методов/функций/процедур наподобие `prepare` раньше было оправдано. Теперь, когда все запросы кэшируются, это стало рудиментом. Если посмотреть по ссылкам: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33667857/5045688), [2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3.2/odpnt/CommandPrepare.html#GUID-78190DD6-CFEE-403C-B51F-2C5388C3F558) - об этом прямо говорится в документации. Метод есть, но он ничего не делает.

В некоторых языках/фреймворках до сих пор есть такое понятие как `prepared statement` или `prepared query`. В других вместо этого существует термин `parameterized query`. В обоих случаях, это параметризованный запрос.

Суть в том, что параметризованный запрос, хранящийся в СУБД, можно многократно выполнять с разными значениями параметров. При этом он не парсится повторно. То есть он подготовлен (prepared) один раз и на этом всё.

---

Теперь собственно ответ на ваш вопрос.

Проверять явно в коде ничего не нужно. При восстановления соединения после обрыва, при выполнении запроса его план будет взят из кэша, если он там есть.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за комментарий. 0xDB дал правильную ссылку выше (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/sql-processing.html). КАЖДЫЙ выданный запрос парсится повторно. Другое дело, что если он найден в Shared Pool, то сервер повторно не подключает оптимизатор (стрелка Soft Parse). Мой вопрос был  связан с тем, что ранее в Devart ODAC я мог видеть, открыт ли курсор на сервере (свойство Prepared=true) или нет, и управлять этим свойством = открывать/закрывать курсор на сервере. Теперь, используя C# и Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, я такой возможности не имею.